# Repassar um array de um formulário para PHP através de AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, array

Tenho este formulário:

jQuery

```
(function($) {
  AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="dados[][nome]" id="dados[][nome]" class="form-control" value=""></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="dados[][nome]" id="dados[][nome]" class="form-control" value=""></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="dados[][nome]" id="dados[][nome]" class="form-control" value=""></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="dados[][nome]" id="dados[][nome]" class="form-control" value=""></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"><span class="fa fa-minus"></button></button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#convidados-table").append(newRow);

    return false;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Para entender melhor, modifiquei o código... Como eu faria este ajuste para array?

Comment: O ID você pode tirar, ele nunca pode se repetir na página. Quando você clona a linha vai duplicar o ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, com um contador no JS

```
<input type="text" name="dados[][nome]" class="form-control" value="">
<input type="text" name="dados[][faixaetaria]" class="form-control" value="">
<input type="text" name="dados[][telefone]" class="form-control" value="">
<input type="text" name="dados[][email]" class="form-control" value="">
```

E no jQuery você pode fazer igual no HTML, sem ID e com os *name* iguais do formulário.

```
var cont = 1;
$("#adicionar_convidado").click(function() {
   cont++;
   var campos_novos = "\
   <div class='dep_fc' id='dep_fc'> \
      <div class='col-md-12' style='padding: 5px;'> \
         <div class='col-md-3'> \
            <input type='text' name='dados[nome]["+cont+"]' placeholder='Nome' class='form-control'></div> \
            <div class='col-md-2'><input type='text' name='dados[faixaetaria]["+cont+"]' placeholder='Faixa Etária' class='form-control'></div> \
            <div class='col-md-3'><input type='text' name='dados[telefone]["+cont+"]' placeholder='Telefone' class='form-control'></div> \
            <div class='col-md-3'><input type='text' name='dados[email]["+cont+"]' placeholder='E-mail'  class='form-control'></div> \
            <div class='col-md-1'><button class='btn btn-default remove' type='button'><span class='fa fa-minus'></span></button></div> \
         </div> \
      </div> \
   </div>";
   $("#dep").append(campos_novos);
});
```

---

No meu caso iria retornar:

```
"dados" => array:4 [
    "nome" => array:2 [
      0 => "A"
      1 => "E"
    ]
    "faixaetaria" => array:2 [
      0 => "B"
      1 => "F"
    ]
    "telefone" => array:2 [
      0 => "C"
      1 => "G"
    ]
    "email" => array:2 [
      0 => "D"
      1 => "H"
    ]
]
```

Daí o PHP seria:

```
foreach($dados['nome'] as $key => $value){
    $fe       = $dados['faixaetaria'][$key];
    $email    = $dados['email'][$key];
    $telefone = $dados['telefone'][$key];
    $nome     = $value;
}
```

Comment: Assim não dará certo, preciso que o retorno seja: array ( 0 ( nome = nome, email = email, telefone = telefone, idade = idade) (1 (nome = nome, email = email, telefone = telefone, idade = idade) ) e assim por diante

Comment: Do jeito que você quer terá que criar um contador. Se for do meu jeito você vai receber no PHP com um Foreach apenas em um campo e utilizará o indíce para pegar os outros.

Comment: Como iria retornar? Neste seu caso

Comment: Nessa sua útima edição, ele vai retornar em arrays separados por isso preciso criar o contador dentro das divs, ou seja, a primeira linha é 0, as outras, 1, 2, 3... ai daria certo, note que é tabela e não div. Por isso modifiquei minha questão

Comment: Eu fiz do jeito que você precisa, com um contador.

Comment: Fiz um pouco diferente, mas usei a logica do cont =1, cont++, pra fazer a contagem na hora de incluir a row, deu certo, obrigado! :) Um próspero 2017 pra você.

Comment: Neste caso fica mais fácil pra inserir usando o codeigniter:     [dados] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => teste1
                    [faixaetaria] => 33
                    [telefone] => srandrebail@gmail.com
                    [email] => (41) 99 99999999
                )

Comment: Entendi. EEEEE Code Igniter, só dando dor de cabeça.